# Highcharts: how to dynamically set up max value of yAxis, based on the displayed data?

Tags: highcharts

I have two charts [here](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/5xothyvu/3/) where I was using static data for the candles. Let's consider the second Y-axis, where the max value for the few given candles is 215.

[image]

In the code I provided, the max value for this y Axes are set as:

```
yAxis: [{
   ...
}, {
    max: 215*4
}],
```

From where we can see that I am hardcoding the value for the max as `215*4`. What I need to do is, to be able to dynamically get the current value and to multiply it by 4.

I tried it like:

```
yAxis: [{
    ...
}, {
    max: this.getExtremes().dataMax * 4
}],
```

But seems is not working and seems that `this.getExtremes()` can be used in the events only. So is there any way how can I accomplish to set up max value depending on the current displayed max value?

I also tried the following (but it still does not work).

```
render: function() {
  let yAxisExtremesVolumeMax = this.yAxis[1].getExtremes().dataMax;
  this.yAxis[1].update({
    max: yAxisExtremesVolumeMax * 4
  });
},
```

Anyway, I am not sure that I want to check it this way, since the `render` event can be called too many times, so I prefer other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this solution with the load instead the render. Doing update in the render callback creates the infinity loop. Code:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this,
          max = chart.series[1].dataMax;

        chart.yAxis[1].update({
          max: max * 4
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c6qjnf5z/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this solution...

```
load: function () {
    let { min, max } = this.yAxis[1].getExtremes();
    max = max * 4;
    this.yAxis[1].setExtremes(min, max);
}
```